# Can I ask for verification of work as opposed to asking people to solve problems?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, solution-verification

I often find problems in textbooks or on the internet that don't have answers posted anywhere. Is it OK to do the work for these problems and then ask to have my work verified? All the questions I have ever seen on this site involve someone getting stuck in the process of solving a problem and they want hints on how to continue or complete solutions that they can learn from.

Comment: There is a significant precedent for proof-verification on MSE; in fact there is a tag for this purpose. I don't see why solutions to non-proof problems would be any different.

Comment: Some related older posts:
[Best way of asking “check my proof” questions](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4597/best-way-of-asking-check-my-proof-questions), 
[Questions that Ask to Verify Solution to Problem](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/8424/questions-that-ask-to-verify-solution-to-problem),
[Are “please check my proof” type of questions proper?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1878/are-please-check-my-proof-type-of-questions-proper)

Comment: I suppose I should have done a better job checking for previous questions like mine... Thanks for the answers!

Comment: It's OK to ask proof verification questions, but consider this too. If you're asking for verification it sounds like you might be uneasy about a particular part of the proof. If so, you should definitely mention that particular part. The more specific you are about a problem, the easier you make it for users to write a helpful answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, certainly. There are appropriate tags for such questions:

- [proof-verification](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/proof-verification) for verifying and giving advice on your proofs of theorems
- [solution-verification](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solution-verification) for verifying and giving advice on your solutions of problems more generally (I tend to use this one for verifying non-proof, computational problems.)